# LazyColumn disable auto scrolling when last item content is getting updated

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using LazyColumn in jetpack compose to display ai chat messages. I am using reverseLayout = true to show latest messages at the bottom. There is some issue with scrolling, I am using rememberLazyListState it works well except when ai response message is getting generated. The last message content is updated every time when the ai is generating response. When I manually try to scroll backward when response is getting generated, the scroll is not remembered, it keeps scrolling automatically until response is completed. Please, see this [video](https://youtu.be/JHC6LX3i7s0) with this issue. But, auto scroll stops when scroll to different item than generating message, even when last message is getting generated. Don't know this issue occurs is only when last message is visible and generating.

Please, help how to resolve this issue.

Here is the code:

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 12.dp)
        //.padding(bottom = listBottomPadding.value)//DEVA REMOVE PADDING
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            isButtonVisible = lazyListState.canScrollBackward
        }
        .fillMaxSize(),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 120.dp, bottom = 8.dp),
    reverseLayout = true,
    state = lazyListState,
) {
    items(items = messages,
        key = { message -> message.id }) { message ->
        MessageBubble(message = message, onImage = onImage)
    }
}
```

Update:

I found whats causing the auto scrolling issue its reverseLayout = true, because items are getting updated at bottom, the layout has to move up when items changes. But, don't know why this is not happening when scrolled to other items other than bottom last item. How to make this work on bottom last item too?